# Set background color in *ngFor

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am not sure whether the title will do the justice to my question or not but here it is.

I have an `md-toolbar` from angular material2 where I am looping for dynamic values:

```
<md-toolbar (click)="selectedToolbarValue(key.Name)" *ngFor="let key of arrayOfKeys; let i=index">
       <span>{{key.Name}}</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

Now I want to set the background color for a particular clicked toolbar by `[ngClass]`. This is what I did:

```
<md-toolbar [ngClass]="{'toolBarColor':setToolbarStyle}" (click)="selectedToolbarValue(key.Name)" *ngFor="let key of arrayOfKeys; let i=index">
       <span>{{key.Name}}</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

In `.ts`:

```
setToolbarStyle:boolean=false;
selectedToolbarValue(value){
    this.setToolbarStyle = true;
    //other code
}
```

In `.scss`:

```
.toolBarColor{
background-color:blue;
color:#fff;
}
```

Now what is happening with the above code is, it is styling all the toolbar values that are part of the loop. How do I style only that toolbar which is being clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function in the `ngClass` expression instead of the value. The function can take an index or any other unique identifier:

```
<md-toolbar [ngClass]="{'toolBarColor':setToolbarStyle(i)}" (click)="selectedToolbarValue(key.Name, i)" *ngFor="let key of arrayOfKeys; let i=index">

toolbarStyleIndex: number;

setToolbarStyle(i) {
    return i===toolbarStyleIndex;
}

selectedToolbarValue(value, i){
    this.toolbarStyleIndex = i;
    //other code
}
```

Comment: you have changed the `selectedToolbarValue(i)` method to pass `i` instead of `key.Name`. Wouldn't that change his code's behavior? Any specific reason for that?

Comment: @Faisal, it's just an example, you can pass as many parameters as you want. Or use other key instead of index, the way you did in your answer. The point is to use function in the `ngClass`. I've udpated my answer a bit. The problem is that that `key.Name` may not really be unique, while `index` will definitely will

Comment: Your answer makes more sense than mine (Y)

Comment: thanks, but yours doesn't need an additional property, I like that approach.

Comment: But if you see it in this plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/DeDfOBTvERAZ2dlsttOF?p=preview its capturing the click event but not applying any styles.

Comment: @AakashThakur, it's because you didn't specify `styleUrls` for the component decorator. See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uOlPGZpt6ML4leOyMBhR?p=preview).

Comment: @Maximus Ohh my bad..Thanks for the solution though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add setToolbarStyle as boolean property in arrayOfKeys. Then do the following changes:

```
<md-toolbar [ngClass]="{'toolBarColor': setToolbarStyle(key)}" 
            (click)="selectedToolbarValue(key.Name)" 
            *ngFor="let key of arrayOfKeys; let i=index">        
    <span>{{key.Name}}</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

In your component class, define the method `setToolbarStyle(key)`:

```
setToolbarStyle(key:any) : boolean {
    key.setToolbarStyle = true;
    return key.setToolbarStyle;
}
```

Comment: Adding boolean prop to arrayofKeys would mean altering the array itself. The array itself is a lot complicated. Can you please suggest something that wouldn't change the array and still achieve the requirement.

Comment: See the answer from maximus